# Can CumulusCI Migrate Files?

Tags: data, files, cumulusci

I'm using CumulusCI to automate org setup, deployment and data migration. This is all working great but I have run into a problem using the tool to migrate files.

Is this a known limitation of CumulusCI or is there a way to extract ContentVersion data and load it into an org using the `extract_dataset` and `load_dataset` tasks?

I've imported files before using data loader and if I recall this involves having the file stored locally and the PathOnClient field provided when importing.

What I've tried: using CumulusCI and treating ContentVersion like any other SObject, extracting the VersionData field simply returns a URL to retrieve the VersionData rather than the binary data which isn't particularly helpful.

- Even if I could get the binary data from the ContentVersion record, can CumulusCI load it in a new org?
- I think that a different endpoint might need to be used for inserting binary data which isn't the standard bulk/rest API that CumulusCI uses.

Does anyone know if this possible with CumulusCI or will I have to migrate the files another way?